# how can i use regex with locate command in linux

Tags: regex, linux

I want to use the locate command with regex but i am not able to use it.

I want to find `pip` file which is in /usr folder. i am trying this

`locate -r "/usr/*pip"`

Comment: That regex will match things like `/usrpip` and `/usr///////pip`.  Is that what you want?

Comment: If you know it's in the /usr folder, why do you want to find it? Or maybe you want something like `find /usr -name '*pip*'`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To use globbing characters in your query you shouldn't specify regex (as you do with `-r` option), so just do:

```
locate "/usr/*pip"
```

From the man page:

> If --regex is not specified, PATTERNs can contain globbing characters.
> If any PATTERN contains no globbing characters, locate behaves as  if
> the pattern were *PATTERN*.

Answer (score 2):

I would do so:   `locate -r '/usr/.*pip'`

Comment: Thanks for sharing! I'm having hardtime using normal regex and to figure out why it doesn't work, at least this is what I need for to find services... why it can't use `'.{0,}'` ?